# Print Java Object graph

Tags: java, logging, spring

Please share your comments and better ideas, to print java graph, which manipulates selected (`@Mask`) fields as XX, thus avoid logging confidential data, through this tool.

[GitHub](https://github.com/senthilaru/sp-util)

```
public class MaskLogger {
    private static final String SERIAL_VERSION_UID = "serialVersionUID";
    private static final String ELEMENT_DATA = "elementData";
    private static final String JAVA_LANG = "java.lang";
    private final static String EQAULS = "=";
    private final static String SQ_BRACKET_OPEN = "[";
    private final static String SQ_BRACKET_CLOSE = "]";
    private final static String BRACE_OPEN = "(";
    private final static String BRACE_CLOSE = ")";
    private final static String COMMA = ", ";
    private final static String STRING = "java.lang.String";

    public <T> String toString(T instance) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(100);
        result.append(SQ_BRACKET_OPEN);
        Field[] fields = instance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        int noOfFields = fields.length;
        for (Field field : fields) {
            noOfFields--;
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (excludeField(instance, field)) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                if (!needDeepDive(field)) {
                    result.append(field.getName());
                    result.append(EQAULS);
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Mask.class)) {
                        result.append("XX");
                    } else {
                        result.append(field.get(instance));
                    }
                    if (noOfFields != 0) {
                        result.append(COMMA);
                    }
                } else if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                    Collection<?> collection = (Collection<?>) field.get(instance);
                    result.append(field.getName());
                    result.append(EQAULS);
                    result.append(SQ_BRACKET_OPEN);
                    for (Object object : collection) {
                        result.append(toString(object));
                    }
                    result.append(SQ_BRACKET_CLOSE + COMMA);
                } else if (field.getType().isArray()) {
                    Object[] collection = (Object[]) field.get(instance);
                    result.append(field.getName());
                    result.append(EQAULS);
                    result.append(BRACE_OPEN);
                    int noOfStringFields = collection.length;
                    for (Object object : collection) {
                        noOfStringFields--;
                        if (object == null && noOfStringFields == 0) {
                            result.delete(result.length() - 1, result.length());
                        } else if (object == null) {
                            continue;
                        } else if (object.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(STRING)) {
                            result.append(object.toString());
                            result.append(COMMA);
                        } else {
                            result.append(toString(object));
                        }
                    }
                    result.deleteCharAt(result.length() - 1);
                    result.append(BRACE_CLOSE);
                } else {
                    result.append(toString(field.get(instance)));
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                return "Error occurred while masking input object:" + e.getMessage();
            }

        }
        result.append(SQ_BRACKET_CLOSE);
        return result.toString();
    }

    /**
     * It excludes the unnecessary fields in the object graph.
     *
     * @param instance
     * @param field
     * @return true/false
     */
    private <T> boolean excludeField(T instance, Field field) {
        if ((instance instanceof Collection<?> && !field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(ELEMENT_DATA))
                || field.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(SERIAL_VERSION_UID)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * It checks whether needs to dive deep into the object graph to scan
     * through the @Mask annotation
     *
     * @param field
     * @return true/false
     */
    private boolean needDeepDive(Field field) {
        boolean result = true;
        if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Mask.class)) {
            result = false;
        } else if (!field.getType().isArray()
                && (field.getType().getCanonicalName().startsWith(JAVA_LANG) || field.getType().isPrimitive())) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

package com.immibytes.util.log;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.FIELD })
public @interface Mask {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it using one line of code with simple and opensource [java object layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) tool:

```
public <T> String toString(T instance) {
    return GraphLayout.parseInstance(instance).toPrintable();
}
```

that tool also can show the memory footprint of given object with all its fields.

Comment: But, the requirement is to intercept each field or object while printing the graph. The aim is to check the availability of `@Mask` annotation and manipulate the result.